# Why nodejs is not connecting mongo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have this code in node:

```
"use strict"
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var UserGateway = function(mongoURL) {
  this.mongoURL = mongoURL;
}

UserGateway.prototype.connect = function() {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      MongoClient.connect(mongoURL, function(err, db) {
        if(err) {
           reject(err);
        }
        resolve(db);
   });
});
}

UserGateway.prototype.getUsername = function(_userId) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      connect().then((db) => {

       let user = db.collection('user').findOne({"_id":_userId});
       disconnect();
       resolve(user);
   });
  });
}

UserGateway.prototype.disconnect = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    MongoClient.close(function(err, db) {
      if(err) {
        reject(err)
      }
      resolve(db)
    })
 })
}

module.exports = UserGateway;
```

And i execute it with:

```
var UserGateway = require("./src/userGateway.js")

var userGT = new UserGateway("mongodb://localhost:27017/UserSports")
userGT.getUsername(1).then(userName => {
   console.log(userName)
})
```

Anyone has an idea where the error is? I've been programming in js so little.
My idea was to connect to mongo and retrieve a username giving the  user Id, and to let getUsername manage the connect and disconnect.

EDIT>

I solved it, it was just that i was calling the connection to mongo in a bad way, i was using:
    MongoClient.connect(mongoURL //whatever
Instead of 
     MongoClient.connect(this.mongoURL //whatever

Comment: Can you show the error you got? Write details of your problem to get help faster, and to help others with same problem to use your question!

Comment: Executing the code does not get an error, it simply does not connect to mongo and does nothing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code itself may not be the problem. Based upon your comment above:
*"Executing the code does not get an error, it simply does not connect to mongo and does nothing :( –"*

I would assume the hidden problem is here:

`this.mongoURL = mongoURL;`

Probably your mongoURL variable is not correct.

The mongoURL would need as follows (assuming role creation and username and pw):

`MongoDBurl_prefix + User_name + ':' + Password + url_ip + MongoDBport + MongoDBname`;

Check to see if your mongoURL is formulated correctly, supplies the needed parameters and connects.

If you do not have a username & password for the specific role (not a good idea), then access would be simple as follows:

`MongoDBurl_prefix + url_ip + MongoDBport + MongoDBname`;

One more problem may be causing it to fail. The user role you are using does not have readWrite access or whatever access you require in the Roles on that DB.